# Visual Studio Code C++ Build finished with error(s)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build-error

I'm trying to run a simple hello world application. Whenever I try to build using g++ it gives me the following error. I can't generate the .exe file or anything. I re-installed mingw using msys2. Walked through tutorials etc.. same problem occurs. The paths provided below are supposed to be correct *made sure of it*

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g3 -Wall H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.cpp -o H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.

Build finished with error(s).
 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I walked through tutorial to build and debug c++ from the beginning to the end still the same problem. **tasks.json** code is below. I sticked with default "args" but same problem as well. I copied the tutorials args same problem.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                // "${fileDirname}" also gives the same problem.
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Run C/C++: g++.exe",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe -g3 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

edit:
helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it using Run Code using CodeRunner extension it runs normally, but Run/Debug C++ Code gives the error provided.
Whenever I try to see the errors, it shows nothing.

Another Edit:
when running `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g3 -Wall H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.cpp -o H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.exe` in cmd it build successfully and generate the .exe file.

Comment: I'm guessing **launch.json** is incorrect. Could you post that.

Comment: The other thing to try is to open a command window and execute the build command `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g3 -Wall H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.cpp -o H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.exe` there and see what happens.

Comment: It writes system cannot find path. Check all the paths in the command. Smth probably does not exist. Eg, g++ path

Comment: Just noticed this *I can't generate the .exe file or anything*, so I think the thing to try is the command window test.

Comment: @john when writing that command in cmd or g++ before .cpp file it doesn't give warning and it build actually successfuly ..

Comment: @JenyaKh all the paths are correct .. mingw bin is added in PATH all things up until now are correct ..

Comment: @AbdelrahmanRabah No idea then, personally I would give up and use a decent compiler like Visual Studio

Comment: @john Im using visual studio code mainly for Python and AI but wanted to return to C++ programming, so I thought about combining both in same IDE

Comment: @AbdelrahmanRabah Have you checked `launch.json`? An error there wouldn't explain why you can't generate an exe file but still worth a look.

Comment: @john there is no launch.json generated yet .. I can't even build the program .. when running ```C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g3 -Wall H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.cpp -o H:\VSCode\CPP\helloworld.exe``` in cmd it built successfully  and generated the .exe

Comment: @AbdelrahmanRabah Another thing to try, put a deliberate error in your code. The idea is to test if the compiler is running or not.

Comment: This particular error message always drives me up the wall. _Which_ path?

Comment: @PaulSanders I think I don't quiet understand ur question but if you're talking about the environment variables, for both users the admin and system

Comment: I'm talking about the error message itself - "The system cannot find the path specified".  Not very helpful, is it?

Comment: @PaulSanders unfortunately there is no other error messages .. when I build the project using cmd it works .. from anywhere ..

Comment: All previewed above is all I can get actually..

Comment: Since I cant build the problem using g++, I used code runner to generate it, and from the .exe I successfully can debug the program. Until now I don't know the problem with g++ and cl from Visual Studio Developer command..

Comment: When you attempted this? Did you close and reopen visual studio code? Was VS Code open when first installing everything?

Comment: VS Code for C++ is not very beginner friendly. You'll have a much easier time if you use an IDE like Visual Studio Community Edition or QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna sound ridiculous, but. What helped me was moving my task.json, launch.json, and settings.json files in the same directory as my .cpp file. Then compiling. Then I deleted the ones in the .cpp directory, and was left with the ones generated from this compilation, and I can fully compile, again, and again, and debug my program.

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping launch.json, setting.json and tasks.json files in same path as the cpp file you are trying to run.

[check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFnDd.png)

Comment: No, these files should be in `.vscode`.

Comment: I was having the same problem but when i moved them my error was resolved and i guess that worked because before while building it was not able to locate the dependencies and all but when moved to same directory it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34936626)